# Recommended DI solution for bundles used inside and outside of OSGi

Tags: dependency-injection, osgi

We use a mixed OSGi and non-OSGi environment. 
Therefore all our produced JARs are Bundles, to enable deployment and runtime both inside and outside of the OSGi container. Therefore, all our are written without any OSGi API integration, and we use a single OSGi extender bundle to register all services as OSGi services.

I would like to use a single DI solution (i.e. the same configuration file(s)) when wiring the system together both inside and outside of the OSGi container. This, rather effectively, prevents me from using simple blueprint DI.

What would you recommend here?
Is there any best practices collected for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Spring.

It will obviously work outside of OSGi, and you can use Spring dm to adapt it to work inside of OSGi.  It simply requires the addition of an osgi context file to bind beans to/from the service registry.

We have used it in multiple projects for several years for Eclipse RCP apps.  It can be used to bind things at the UI level in this particular case as well.

Comment: Man, tell me this doesn't require the whole "SpringSource Tool Suite".

Answer (score 4):

I suggest looking at [pojosr](http://code.google.com/p/pojosr/)

> A service registry that enables OSGi style service registry programs without using an OSGi framework.
>
> The idea is to create something that would make the service and parts of the life cycle layer of OSGi available in environments where it typically isn't.

This allows you to use the normal OSGi Service Registry and Declarative Services, even outside an official OSGi framework, unless you need more than what is offered by Declarative Services

Comment: While interesting, pojosr provides the reverse service of what I desire. I want people to use normal dependency injection (i.e. non-osgi-coloured) in their coding, and have said dependency injection magically work in the same way for the in-OSGi-deployment runtimes.

Comment: +1 PojoSR and DS would be ideal - but may involve quite a bit of change to legacy systems with little test coverage.

Comment: +1 This will work the same both inside and outside OSGi. I don't know what you mean by "normal dependency injection".

Comment: If Declarative Services can be used with PojoSR outside OSGi, you may want to consider the different use cases from your point of view and from others using your library (assuming that is the case), considering both new and legacy code on both sides. If there is not one universally used dependency injection framework, then chances are they will be already using a different one from what you will choose whatever the choice is.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options;

1. Google **[Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)** will work both inside ([implicitly](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/OSGi) and explicitly using [Peaberry](http://code.google.com/p/peaberry/)) and outside.
2. Apache **[Camel](http://camel.apache.org/)** - Camel's [bean binding](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html) will work in OSGi, spring, (AFAIK) all EJB containers (even [JBoss](http://camel.apache.org/camel-jboss.html)) and also will work nicely with Guice.

As it's likely you're running across multiple JVMs, with a mix of nice new OSGi and legacy, Camel's [EIP](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) might be a really good fit.   But you can always get started with Guice and integrate Camel later.

Whatever you decide, it would be wise to ensure *any* Jars built include an OSGi manifest.